# Android Google Map - Map Type selection from FAB menu

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, kotlin, material-ui

I'm trying to create a nice looking menu to change the map type, exactly like what is on Google Maps.. It appears when you click the layers FAB. I don't know if it's a custom FAB menu, or if it animates and opens a fragment.

[image: Screenshot of Google Maps layers menu]

How to achieve this look?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

After much reading and learning, I have managed to fully design the look that I am happy with. For anyone wanting the same look, here is my code and resources below...

**Note:** It is not exactly perfect, may look different on some other devices, and don't judge my coding too much (I am a beginner... I can some refactoring but it gets the job done).

*Extra Points:*

- Written in Kotlin
- Pretty sure requires API 21+. Have not implemented any workaround here for earlier versions
- Open/close of the selection view uses a circular reveal animation, instead of Googles expanding one (I like my implementation better)
- Lack of optimizations may lead to poor performance on low end devices

---

**Resources**

---

[image]
**type_default.png**

[image]
**type_satellite.png**

[image]
**type_terrain.png**

**rounded_rectangle.xml**

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#2962ff" />
    <corners android:radius="10dp" />
</shape>
```

**ic_map_layers.xml**

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:width="24dp"
        android:height="24dp"
        android:viewportWidth="24.0"
        android:viewportHeight="24.0">
    <path
        android:fillColor="#3C4043"
        android:pathData="M11.99,18.54l-7.37,-5.73L3,14.07l9,7 9,-7 -1.63,-1.27 
        -7.38,5.74zM12,16l7.36,-5.73L21,9l-9,-7 -9,7 1.63,1.27L12,16z"/>
</vector>
```

---

**Map Layout File**

---

The code listed here was also nested inside a constraint layout with the map and other FAB, but if you are reading this, I don't think you need to know how to put a map in...

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/map_type_FAB"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true"
    app:backgroundTint="#FFF"
    app:fabSize="mini"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/map_view"
    app:rippleColor="#eff5ff"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_map_layers" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:id="@+id/map_type_selection"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/map_type_background"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map_type_FAB"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/map_type_FAB">


    <View
        android:id="@+id/map_type_default_background"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/map_type_default"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map_type_default"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/map_type_default"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/map_type_default" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/map_type_default"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/type_default"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/map_type_satellite_background"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/map_type_satellite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map_type_satellite"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/map_type_satellite"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/map_type_satellite" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/map_type_satellite"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/type_satellite"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/map_type_terrain"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/map_type_default"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/map_type_terrain_background"
        android:layout_width="54dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/map_type_terrain"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map_type_terrain"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/map_type_terrain"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/map_type_terrain" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/map_type_terrain"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/type_terrain"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView13" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
        android:text="Map Type"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/map_type_default_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Default"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map_type_default"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/map_type_default"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/map_type_default" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/map_type_satellite_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Satellite"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map_type_satellite"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/map_type_satellite"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/map_type_satellite" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/map_type_terrain_text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Terrain"
        android:textColor="#808080"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/map_type_terrain"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/map_type_terrain"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/map_type_terrain" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

---

**Map Fragment**

---

Snippet of code from my onMapReady function. This is the part that isn't the prettiest, but gets the job done.

```
   override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {

    // Initialise the map variable
    map = googleMap

    // When map is initially loaded, determine which map type option to 'select'
    when {
        map.mapType == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE -> {
            map_type_satellite_background.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            map_type_satellite_text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
        }
        map.mapType == GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN -> {
            map_type_terrain_background.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            map_type_terrain_text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
        }
        else -> {
            map_type_default_background.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            map_type_default_text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
        }
    }

    // Set click listener on FAB to open the map type selection view
    mapTypeFAB.setOnClickListener {

        // Start animator to reveal the selection view, starting from the FAB itself
        val anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(
                map_type_selection,
                map_type_selection.width - (map_type_FAB.width / 2),
                map_type_FAB.height / 2,
                map_type_FAB.width / 2f,
                map_type_selection.width.toFloat())
        anim.duration = 200
        anim.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()

        anim.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            override fun onAnimationStart(animation: Animator?) {
                super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
                map_type_selection.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
        })

        anim.start()
        mapTypeFAB.visibility = View.INVISIBLE

    }

    // Set click listener on the map to close the map type selection view
    map.setOnMapClickListener {

        // Conduct the animation if the FAB is invisible (window open)
        if (map_type_FAB.visibility == View.INVISIBLE) {

            // Start animator close and finish at the FAB position
            val anim = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(
                    map_type_selection,
                    map_type_selection.width - (map_type_FAB.width / 2),
                    map_type_FAB.height / 2,
                    map_type_selection.width.toFloat(),
                    map_type_FAB.width / 2f)
            anim.duration = 200
            anim.interpolator = AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()

            anim.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator?) {
                    super.onAnimationEnd(animation)
                    map_type_selection.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                }
            })

            // Set a delay to reveal the FAB. Looks better than revealing at end of animation
            Handler().postDelayed({
                kotlin.run {
                    mapTypeFAB.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                }
            }, 100)
            anim.start()
        }
    }

    // Handle selection of the Default map type
    map_type_default.setOnClickListener {
        map_type_default_background.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        map_type_satellite_background.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        map_type_terrain_background.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        map_type_default_text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
        map_type_satellite_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"))
        map_type_terrain_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"))
        map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
    }

    // Handle selection of the Satellite map type
    map_type_satellite.setOnClickListener {
        map_type_default_background.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        map_type_satellite_background.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        map_type_terrain_background.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        map_type_default_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"))
        map_type_satellite_text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
        map_type_terrain_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"))
        map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE
    }

    // Handle selection of the terrain map type
    map_type_terrain.setOnClickListener {
        map_type_default_background.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        map_type_satellite_background.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        map_type_terrain_background.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        map_type_default_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"))
        map_type_satellite_text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#808080"))
        map_type_terrain_text.setTextColor(Color.BLUE)
        map.mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN
    }
}
```

---

**End Result**

---

This is my end result. Like I said, I am only a beginner, things could definitely be better, but for now, I'm very happy with the result.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution i can think of right now is to:

1. Add a `<CardView>` to your layout:

> ```
>     ...
>    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton 
>       android:id="@+id/fab">  
>
>    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
>       android:id="@+id/cardview"
>       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fab"
>       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fab">
> ```

2. Fill with Views for the dialog
3. Set Visibility to `View.GONE`:

   ```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
       android:id="@+id/cardview"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/fab"
       app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/fab"
       android:visibility="gone">
   ```
4. In your activity set Visibility to `View.Visible`on button click:

   ```
   fab.setOnClickListener{  
     cardview.visibility = View.VISIBLE
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your help mate. It helped me with my ideas :) have posted my answer that I finally completed.

Comment: NicCoe if Ro Ras post helped then up-vote, or accept his answer